# Adding symbols through strings.xml file

Tags: android

I am displaying `Activity's Title` from `strings.xml` file like this

```
setTitle(R.string.add_contact_title);
```

I have following `string` in `strings.xml`

```
<string name="add_contact_title">Anadir Contacto</string>
```

but i want to display title like `Añadir Contacto` instead of `Anadir Contacto`.

is there any way to do this within the *strings.xml* file rather than copying and pasting the characters from another source?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it display ~ beside character instead of above string character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use unicode using the **\u** escape sequence like this:

```
<string name="add_contact_title">A\u00F1adir Contacto</string>
```

See here for a list of common unicode latin characters: http://unicode-table.com/en/#latin-extended-b

Comment: Bad character in \u unicode escape sequence (in A\u223NADIR CONTACTO)

Comment: @Rajesh Jadav you cannot add symbols above characters. Some characters have those symbols built-in automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&#241;`

You can find all the HTML Special Characters in this page

[Special Characters in Android & HTML](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php)

just replace the code where you want to put that character. :-)

Comment: Try using `&#241;` as mentioned in the link

Comment: @ArchitGoel This is Android specific. The &ntilde; will not work, but the &#241; will. Delete the &ntilde; from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. You have to start the special character with `&amp`
i.e for your case it will be like `&#241;`

`<string name="add_contact_title">A`ñ`adir Contacto</string>`

Just check the link which will convert ASCII into Unicode
[ASCII to Unicode](http://www.mikezilla.com/exp0012.html)
and [Unicode Reference](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/02B0-02FF)